# How to solve : No App Check token for request?

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-app-check

There are so many duplicated answers I had tried almost all of them but I am still not able to use Firebase storage image with Glide.

it gives this error:

Unable to instantiate appComponentFactory java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" on path: DexPathList[[],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.fooddonation-3uxLQ9xdyOOMPPLtZPvodw==/lib/x86, /system/lib]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312) at android.app.LoadedApk.createAppFactory(LoadedApk.java:226) at android.app.LoadedApk.updateApplicationInfo(LoadedApk.java:338) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDispatchPackageBroadcast(ActivityThread.java:5388) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1733) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:454) at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)